# ckeditor toolbar doesn't show in asp.net masterpage scenario

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have an asp.net site, .net 4 framework. I'm trying to get the ckeditor up and running. Sorry, I'm a bit new to the ckeditor. There is a quick start guide here that shows you how to implement:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

I originally thought the editor wasn't showing the toolbar. However, after further debug, I believe the ckeditor isn't showing at all, and in fact, the textarea is still all that is showing.

I'm using the same code as on the example in the website. I've reposted that here:

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>
<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
</script>
```

I've included the script ckeditor.js script this way:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DefectEntry3.aspx.cs" Inherits="DefectWriter.DefectEntry3" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script src="App_Data/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong path in the script source. Once I got the right path all is well.